# Apple Xcode 4.3.2There are no valid certificate/private key pairs in the default keychain

Tags: xcode, certificate, warnings, private-key

"There are no valid certificate/private key pairs in the default keychain"
please help.  I get this warning when i try to build or run my app.  It ran fine before I upgraded to Xcode 4.3.2
any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Hi! did you fix the issue? an answer or a comment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't want so sign your code with the certificate.

In the scheme choser I switched from iOS Device to iPad/iPhone 5.1 simulator.
After that I could build the app again.
Earlier simulators need to be downloaded separately.

Hope this helps...

Comment: if you're building into the simulator, you're bypassing the code signing - this does not fix the problem - it works around it

Comment: @coyote i figured it out. i needed to trash my other certificates. regenerate one and get a new .p12 file